# How to increase performance for HTTPS in Oracle Application Server?

Tags: https, oracle-application-server

How can we tune the performance (by perhaps changing the parameters) to make HTTPS faster in an OracleAS?

Thank you

Comment: I would like to know more about which parameters to reconfigure and what are the commands to type.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer to the documentation for tuning standards:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e10108/http.htm#ASPER99079

Here are some relevant pieces that could effect SSL tuning that in my experience can make a difference:
*[Section 5.4.1.1:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e10108/http.htm#CEGEIIBJ)

The SSLSessionCacheTimeout directive in ssl.conf determines how long the server keeps a saved SSL session (the default is 300 seconds). Session state is discarded if it is not used after the specified time period, and any subsequent SSL request must establish a new SSL session and begin the handshake again.*
[Section 5.4.1.3:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e10108/http.htm#ASPER99090)
*If large volumes of data are being protected through SSL, pay close attention to the cipher suite being used. The SSLCipherSuite directive specified in ssl.conf controls the cipher suite. If lower levels of security are acceptable, use a less-secure protocol using a smaller key size (this may improve performance significantly). Finally, test the application using each available cipher suite for the specified security level to find the optimal suite.*